# How to override Wordpress inline !important style

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook

I am using WooCommerce on Wordpress - the 'Add to cart' button on the product page has not changed with my updated global styling as it has an inline style:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt gradient_" style="color: rgb(0,0,0)!important">Add to basket</button>
```

I can't override this with CSS so need to find the code in the template and remove it.  When looking through my template I was able to find this in content-single-product.php

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
</div>
```

Where do I find the hook that I need to edit, presumably

```
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
```

Comment: Based on your posted code there is no need to answer from here, you have to debug on your own.

Comment: @charankumar - can you point me to where the hooks are being referenced? i don't know wordpress that well!

Comment: Your theme is certainly doing that (or a plugin) as by default there is no inline style on add to cart. Normally the customizer allow to change the background color of this button. So you will need to look in the templates located in the woocommerce folder inside your theme on single-product > add-to-cart subfolder (with different templates based on the product type)... It can also be added dynamically by jQuery and it that case it will be more difficult for you to find out the way to change it.

Comment: Please post few lines on top of the line where you find `color: #000000!important`. You do not need to edit woocommerce templates as we can override even `!important` css.

Comment: @KamranSyed I have added the entire HTML element.

Comment: Please check my answer based on HTML provided. @J4G If you find any issue, we are here to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the jquery code you have been used

The code you have used is
`<script>
 jQuery('a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart').removeAttr('style');
         });
  </script>`

Replace the code as

`<script>
 jQuery('a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart').removeAttr('style');
          </script>`

Then it will work,

Comment: Thanks @a.prakash - this doesn't work either for some reason!

Comment: Try this
<script>
 jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeAttr('style');
          </script>

Comment: Hi @J4G there is plugin "customize-woocommerce-shop" in this there line adding this inline color ** customize-woocommerce-shop->includes->js->woo-product-customizer-front-detail.js**
the lines as  follows:
line no:  6` $('.product .single_add_to_cart_button').attr('style','color: '+wpFrontProductCustDetail.product_cust_detail_button_font_color+ ' !important');`     
line no: 8  `$('.product .products .add_to_cart_button').attr('style','color: '+wpFrontProductCustDetail.product_cust_detail_button_font_color+ ' !important');'

Comment it and then try

Comment: you've cracked it!

Answer (score 1):

Template file with "add to cart" button is probably located is wp-content/you-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php (or any file in single-product/add-to-cart)

Comment: I haven't been able to find the button in any of those files

Comment: find such text in the file `<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart">`

Answer (score 1):

Style attribute can be removed using jQuery. You need to add your css in theme style.css or any other place so that it gets loaded in header. Here is the code that can be pasted in functions.php of the current theme.

```
    function ks_footer(){
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function() {
              jQuery('a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart').removeAttr('style'); //3 Red Buttons
              jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeAttr('style');
            }); //Top Blue Button
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ks_footer' );
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FX31FT8TWR3G) is the quick Tryit editor to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: thank you. i get an error for the opening < of the script for some reason!

Comment: Added missing php tags. Should be OK now @J4G.

Comment: that doesn't seem to have worked for me, the style still seems to be applied.

Comment: Open developer tools, console and paste `jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button')` see if you get correct element.@J4G

Comment: it's bizarre, i don't get anything back. you can test it at https://www.allstaruhlmann.com/product/6mm-epee-fork-wrench/

Comment: This is correct selector for the given element. `jQuery('a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart').removeAttr('style');` @J4G Red button

Comment: This is correct selector for the top blue button. `jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').removeAttr('style');` @J4G

Comment: Yes, above two lines are tested on your site and found working. @J4G I am updating the solution with these selectors.

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't remove the style, I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

To customize the add to cart button you just have to open the WordPress customizer. In the WordPress admin go to

**1) Appearance -> Customize and load the customizer.**

Then in the customizer click on Buttons -> Alternate button background color and set your color.

**2) Press Save & Publish and you're done.**

Comment: I already did that which is why I created this question.  That wouldn't work and then I couldn't in CSS either because it turns out !important inline can't be overwritten. I need to get rid of it.